# Shading the 95% confidence interval which was plotted using the termplot function

Tags: r

How can I draw the 95% confidence interval which is plotted using the "termplot" function in a different shading? I would be grateful if you can help me. The code looks as follows:

```
mfit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + pspline(rsbp, df=4), data=data)

termplot(mfit, term=2, se=TRUE, col.term=2, col.se="gray",cex=4, plot=TRUE)
```

summary of data"

-3
down vote
accept
"98418", "98419", "98420", "98421", "98422", "98423", "98424", "98425", "98426", "98427", "98428", "98429", "98430", "98431", "98432", "98433", "98434", "98435", "98436", "98437"), c("time", "status")), type = "right", inputAttributes = structure(list( time = structure(list(label = "tstop", format.spss = "F8.0"), .Names = c("label", "format.spss")), event = structure(list(label = "status", format.spss = "F8.0"), .Names = c("label", "format.spss" ))), .Names = c("time", "event")), class = "Surv"), formula = Surv(data1_merge$tstop, data1_merge$status) ~ data1_merge$age + pspline(rsbp, df = 4), call = coxph(formula = Surv(data1_merge$tstop, data1_merge$status) ~ data1_merge$age + pspline(rsbp, df = 4), data = data1_merge)), .Names = c("coefficients", "var", "var2", "loglik", "iter", "linear.predictors", "residuals", "means", "concordance", "method", "df", "df2", "penalty", "pterms", "assign2", "history", "coxlist2", "printfun", "n", "nevent", "terms", "assign", "wald.test", "y", "formula", "call"), class = c("coxph.penal", "coxph"))

Comment: Try to add the following and see: `rug.type="density", rug=T, density.proportion=.05, se.type="polygon"`

Comment: Thank you. It lead to the following error :There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50). No shading was added.

Comment: well, warnings are not errors. do you see the plot? can you post your data?

Comment: Dear AK88; I am very young in R. I added the data to the initial post.

Comment: Can you use `dput(mfit)`?

Comment: How can I get communication with you in private way? I can not post properly the data.

Comment: I'm afraid, you can't :)). Just run this code and post the outcome: `mfit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + pspline(rsbp, df=4), data=data)` and then `dput(mfit)`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with additional information. **Don't** post it as an additional answer